# Fuzzy Match and Join Two Pandas Dataframes on an Alpha-Numeric ID and a Date

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-sagemaker, fuzzywuzzy

I have two pandas dataframes (these are fake but are similar) that I am trying to merge together where the customer IDs are even just 1% similar and the "detail_svc_date" in df1 "date_of_svc" in df2 are somewhat similar to each other:

df1

detail_svc_date |    usd_net_amt    | customer_id__c

0|  2021-10-01   |    13.05   |  82800409401

1|  2021-05-27| 28.06   |NA

2|  2021-04-21  |6.10   |NA

3|  2021-06-03| 60.25|  85064441801

4|  2021-09-14| 22.13|  85083982901

df2

date_of_svc |comments   |customer_id__c

0|  2021-05-10| NA| 0595716403

1   |2021-04-30|    NA| 5311287401

2   |2021-04-30 |NA|    20449550402

3   |2021-05-03 |   NA| 2707200327405

4   |2021-05-03 |NA |0016229901

I want to fuzzy match these dataframes on the **customer ID** field first, and then the **service date** field (all in one piece of code though).

However, I can't even get it to run just even trying to get some type of match across the customer ID field - I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Sometimes, seemingly out of nowhere, I also get this error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 30.1 GiB for an array with shape (24,
> 168432765) and data type object

Just focusing first on the customer ID field, I have tried:

```
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    """
    :param df_1: the left table to join
    :param df_2: the right table to join
    :param key1: key column of the left table
    :param key2: key column of the right table
    :param threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    :param limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    :return: dataframe with boths keys and matches
    """
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()
    
    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['matches'] = m
    
    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    
    return df_1

 fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, 'customer_id__c', 'customer_id__c', threshold=80)
```

I have also tried

```
import fuzzymatcher

left_on = ["customer_id__c"]

right_on = ["customer_id__c"]

matched_results = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df1,
                                            df2,
                                            left_on,
                                            right_on,
                                            left_id_col='customer_id__c',
                                            right_id_col='customer_id__c')
```

How do I get this to:

1. Work so that it will at least try to match the customer IDs
2. After 1 seems to be working, add in the secondary to condition to not just match on the customer ID but also the "detail_svc_date" in df1 and "date_of_svc" in df2

Thanks in advance!

Mark

df1:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'detail_svc_date': {0: Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-05-27 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2021-04-21 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2021-06-03 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2021-09-14 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2021-06-08 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2021-09-24 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2021-10-12 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2021-03-26 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2021-12-27 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2021-12-15 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2021-06-14 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2021-02-06 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2021-08-12 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2021-01-08 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2021-12-10 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2021-06-18 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2021-04-16 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2021-12-14 00:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2021-09-03 00:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2021-05-18 00:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2021-12-31 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2021-09-02 00:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2021-07-19 00:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2021-12-20 00:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2021-03-05 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2021-05-21 00:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2021-06-23 00:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('2021-03-06 00:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2021-11-20 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('2021-06-21 00:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2021-12-10 00:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('2021-09-22 00:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2021-06-04 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2021-09-17 00:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('2021-10-25 00:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('2021-03-30 00:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2021-02-18 00:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2021-01-26 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('2021-09-09 00:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2021-03-08 00:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2021-07-22 00:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('2021-06-25 00:00:00')}, 'usd_net_amt': {0: Decimal('13.05'), 1: Decimal('28.06'), 2: Decimal('6.10'), 3: Decimal('60.25'), 4: Decimal('22.13'), 5: Decimal('13.59'), 6: Decimal('14.77'), 7: Decimal('8.54'), 8: Decimal('23.41'), 9: Decimal('6.92'), 10: Decimal('13.31'), 11: Decimal('8.79'), 12: Decimal('45.23'), 13: Decimal('67.53'), 14: Decimal('72.91'), 15: Decimal('23.45'), 16: Decimal('41.03'), 17: Decimal('59.51'), 18: Decimal('110.05'), 19: Decimal('36.49'), 20: Decimal('164.03'), 21: Decimal('3.65'), 22: Decimal('3.28'), 23: Decimal('235.02'), 24: Decimal('9.39'), 25: Decimal('310.15'), 26: Decimal('2.62'), 27: Decimal('2.61'), 28: Decimal('52.16'), 29: Decimal('22.52'), 30: Decimal('3.64'), 31: Decimal('24.44'), 32: Decimal('8.62'), 33: Decimal('262.24'), 34: Decimal('73.26'), 35: Decimal('91.74'), 36: Decimal('18.13'), 37: Decimal('1956.93'), 38: Decimal('51.89'), 39: Decimal('4.07'), 40: Decimal('55.36'), 41: Decimal('116.13'), 42: Decimal('56.54'), 43: Decimal('52.91'), 44: Decimal('6.13'), 45: Decimal('625.63'), 46: Decimal('13.23'), 47: Decimal('51.47'), 48: Decimal('9.54'), 49: Decimal('129.13')}, 'customer_id__c': {0: '82800409401', 1: <NA>, 2: <NA>, 3: '85064441801', 4: '85083982901', 5: '85062515801', 6: '85083319301', 7: '85078351503', 8: '85047748402', 9: <NA>, 10: '85076001704', 11: '85071220703', 12: '85068078602', 13: '85073868101', 14: '85085607401', 15: <NA>, 16: '85042610902', 17: '85084185703', 18: '85063116501', 19: '85023633201', 20: '85055153301', 21: '85054034002', 22: <NA>, 23: '82009238303', 24: '85077327002', 25: '85079892102', 26: '85053929602', 27: <NA>, 28: '85073323701', 29: '82801042801', 30: '85068971302', 31: '85077901204', 32: '85080903202', 33: '85076730902', 34: '85086744501', 35: '85077210901', 36: '85070179601', 37: '85040105802', 38: '85082807702', 39: '85087090002', 40: '85073160301', 41: <NA>, 42: '85081454801', 43: <NA>, 44: '85065738803', 45: '85042672701', 46: '85082681102', 47: '85080126301', 48: '85036059501', 49: '85022721702'}} )`

df2:

`df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'date_of_svc': {0: Timestamp('2021-05-10 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-04-30 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2021-04-30 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2021-04-17 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2021-04-12 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2021-04-30 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2021-05-12 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2021-05-04 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2021-05-16 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2021-05-06 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2021-05-06 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2021-04-28 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2021-05-06 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2021-05-05 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2021-05-11 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2021-04-16 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2021-05-10 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2021-04-29 00:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2021-06-14 00:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2021-05-14 00:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2021-04-23 00:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2021-04-29 00:00:00'), 25: Timestamp('2021-05-03 00:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 27: Timestamp('2021-05-04 00:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 29: Timestamp('2021-05-06 00:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2021-05-02 00:00:00'), 31: Timestamp('2021-05-05 00:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2021-05-10 00:00:00'), 33: Timestamp('2021-05-11 00:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'), 35: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 37: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2021-10-30 00:00:00'), 39: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2021-11-06 00:00:00'), 41: Timestamp('2021-11-03 00:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 43: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 45: Timestamp('2021-11-13 00:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), 49: Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00')}, 'comments': {0: <NA>, 1: <NA>, 2: <NA>, 3: <NA>, 4: <NA>, 5: <NA>, 6: <NA>, 7: <NA>, 8: <NA>, 9: <NA>, 10: <NA>, 11: <NA>, 12: <NA>, 13: <NA>, 14: <NA>, 15: <NA>, 16: <NA>, 17: <NA>, 18: <NA>, 19: <NA>, 20: <NA>, 21: <NA>, 22: <NA>, 23: <NA>, 24: <NA>, 25: <NA>, 26: <NA>, 27: <NA>, 28: <NA>, 29: <NA>, 30: <NA>, 31: <NA>, 32: <NA>, 33: <NA>, 34: <NA>, 35: <NA>, 36: <NA>, 37: <NA>, 38: <NA>, 39: <NA>, 40: <NA>, 41: <NA>, 42: <NA>, 43: <NA>, 44: <NA>, 45: <NA>, 46: <NA>, 47: <NA>, 48: <NA>, 49: <NA>}, 'customer_id__c': {0: '0595716403', 1: '5311287401', 2: '20449550402', 3: '2707200327405', 4: '0016229901', 5: '82004226502', 6: '3851651701', 7: '20583152206', 8: '5380404501', 9: '5380424101', 10: '0010734702', 11: '20008128402', 12: '20008128401', 13: '20940095901', 14: '20008128403', 15: '82014334202', 16: '20614506101', 17: '20894004401', 18: '4515357802', 19: '20978184001', 20: '1264937', 21: '244N00008344401', 22: '0010417401', 23: '0010988401', 24: <NA>, 25: '0010109002', 26: '20924686401', 27: '41599012701', 28: '20931179101', 29: '20925239501', 30: '20044229102', 31: '20044229102', 32: '20925239501', 33: '244N00007804901', 34: '20561071503', 35: '85073531102', 36: '20143720802', 37: <NA>, 38: '0013913101', 39: <NA>, 40: '20164103701', 41: '85045367701', 42: <NA>, 43: '20624895901', 44: '5311564101', 45: '27030219601', 46: '479880855504', 47: '85056556701', 48: '20918958701', 49: '20888698602'}} )`